# Windsor Castle IoC Thread Safety Static Variables

Tags: webforms, thread-safety, castle-windsor, transient

I have a question for the Ioc gurus out there.
I am working with a co-worker to wrap our minds around Castle Windsor IoC. We are having a difference of opinion about static Domain Service objects within asp.Net webforms. We have a static factory called BLServiceFactory in our Infrastructure layer that retrieves the container.

```
public sealed class BLServiceFactory
{
    private static BLServiceFactory _instance = new BLServiceFactory();


    IWindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer();
    public static BLServiceFactory Instance
    {

        get
        {return _instance;}
    }

    public T Create<T>()
    {
        return (T)_container[typeof(T)];
    }

    private BLServiceFactory()
    {

        _container.AddComponent("DataContext", typeof(DAL.DataContextFactory), typeof(DAL.CPContextFactory));
        _container.AddComponent("Repository", typeof(DAL.IRepository<>), typeof(DAL.Repository<>));
        _container.AddComponent("UserManager", typeof(BL.IUserManager), typeof(BL.UserManager));
        _container.AddComponent("RoleService", typeof(BL.IRoleService), typeof(BL.RoleService));
    }
```

}

We are pulling instances from the factory in our code behinds like this.

```
public partial class PrintList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private static readonly ISchoolManager _schoolService = BLServiceFactory.Instance.Create<ISchoolManager>(); 

    Models.TechSchool _tech;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _tech = _schoolService.GetSchoolForTechPrep(Profile.UserName);

    }

    protected void DoOtherStuff...
    {
      _schoolService.Foo(_tech);
    }

}
```

To me this looks like we will be serving up the same instance to every session. That would indeed be bad! My co-worker thinks that since all of our Domain Services are marked Transient, each page request will get a new instance.

I have also read a bit about memory leaks due to objects marked transient not released for garbage collection. Has this been addressed in the latest release of Castle Windsor, or should I be explicitly releasing objects? Of course as it stands now, all the objects are static and this would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The `BLServiceFactory` is a *service locator*. I recommend using [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) instead of your own if you're going to use a service locator. Component registration does *not* belong inside the service locator.

Now, in the code you posted, there is no mention of those components being transient, unless you marked them with the `[Transient]` attribute. If you didn't, those components will be singletons, which is the default lifestyle in Windsor.

Since the variable `_schoolService`  in `PrintList` is static, the same instance of `ISchoolManager` will be used for all requests to the `PrintList` page. If you really want it to be transient, remove the "static" keyword.

About releasing components, see [this article](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor.aspx).

BTW: `AddComponent`-style registration is deprecated, use `Register()` instead.